# Package.json script cannot find newly created folder - Windows 10

Tags: javascript, angular, package.json

In my Angular app I try to create a `dist` folder with `scripts` in it while `index.html` is placed in the root folder. This is possible with some flag options. I try to automate this by adding it to my package.json scripts but my syntax seems to be incomplete or wrong.

The first halve of the script works fine but the second one doesn't. When I execute the `move` script separately it works fine. How can I fix my syntax so the move script runs as well?

Current script:
`"build:prod": "ng build --prod --output-path=\"dist/scripts\" --deployUrl=\"scripts/\" && move ./dist/scripts/index.html ./dist"`

My dev environment is on **Windows 10**

Comment: try `mv` instead of `move` and get admin rights

Comment: @Greedo is right, move isn't a system command, if it's a script you wrote in package.json you need to write it as `"build:prod": "ng build --prod --output-path=\"dist/scripts\" --deployUrl=\"scripts/\" && npm run move ./dist/scripts/index.html ./dist"`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Sorry I forgot to mention I'm on `Windows`.... Not sure whether `mv` is going to work that way?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I was not escaping the `/` correctly. Below the fully working script.

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --output-path=\"dist/scripts\" --deployUrl=\"scripts/\" && mv ./dist/scripts/index.html || move .\\dist\\scripts\\index.html .\\dist\\"
```